# OpenVZ Failed to start LVM2 PV scan

Tags: linux, lvm, openvz

I am running OpenVZ, I have created a logical drive using `lvcreate` all works well when setting it up but when i power cycle the machine it's giving me some errors on boot;

```
[FAILED] Failed to start LVM2 PV scan on device 9:124.
See 'systemctl status lvm2-pvscan@9:124.service' for details.

[FAILED] Failed to start LVM2 PV scan on device 259:3.
See 'systemctl status lvm2-pvscan@259:3.service' for details.
```

Once the machine is booted i run lvdisplay it returns the information about the volume but the status is not available.

```
LV Status              NOT available
```

If i log in and run;

```
systemctl start lvm2-pvscan@9:124.service
systemctl start lvm2-pvscan@259:3.service
```

It doesn't return any errors and the LV status becomes available again.

My LVM version info is as follows;

```
LVM version:     2.02.171(2)-RHEL7 (2017-05-03)
Library version: 1.02.140-RHEL7 (2017-05-03)
Driver version:  4.35.0
Configuration:   ./configure --build=x86_64-virtuozzo-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-virtuozzo-linux-gnu --program-prefix= --disable-dependency-tracking --prefix=/usr --exec-prefix=/usr --bindir=/usr/bin --sbindir=/usr/sbin --sysconfdir=/etc --datadir=/usr/share --includedir=/usr/include --libdir=/usr/lib64 --libexecdir=/usr/libexec --localstatedir=/var --sharedstatedir=/var/lib --mandir=/usr/share/man --infodir=/usr/share/info --with-default-dm-run-dir=/run --with-default-run-dir=/run/lvm --with-default-pid-dir=/run --with-default-locking-dir=/run/lock/lvm --with-usrlibdir=/usr/lib64 --enable-lvm1_fallback --enable-fsadm --with-pool=internal --enable-write_install --with-user= --with-group= --with-device-uid=0 --with-device-gid=6 --with-device-mode=0660 --enable-pkgconfig --enable-applib --enable-cmdlib --enable-dmeventd --enable-blkid_wiping --enable-python2-bindings --with-cluster=internal --with-clvmd=corosync --enable-cmirrord --with-udevdir=/usr/lib/udev/rules.d --enable-udev_sync --with-thin=internal --enable-lvmetad --with-cache=internal --enable-lvmpolld --enable-lvmlockd-dlm --enable-lvmlockd-sanlock --enable-dmfilemapd
```

If anyone has run into this before i would love to know how to cure it, i have been trying now for days;

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Description:**

The system does not boot normally when using LVM inside /etc/fstab 
It fails with the following error: 
***[FAILED] Failed to start LVM2 PV scan on device 3:1.***
See 'systemctl status lvm2-pvscan@3:1.service' for details.

**Workaround:**

Disable the WRL9 lvm2 services and create a new one, based on the one from WRL8

```
 # systemctl disable lvm2-lvmetad.service
 # systemctl disable lvm2-lvmetad.socket
 # systemctl disable lvm2-monitor.service
 # systemctl disable lvm2-pvscan@.service
 # systemctl mask lvm2-lvmetad.service
 # systemctl mask lvm2-lvmetad.socket
 # systemctl mask lvm2-monitor.service
 # systemctl mask lvm2-pvscan@.service

 # cat > /lib/systemd/system/lvm2.service << EOF
[Unit]
Description=LVM activation
DefaultDependencies=no
Before=local-fs.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/vgchange -ay --sysinit
Type=oneshot
TimeoutSec=0
RemainAfterExit=yes

[Install]
WantedBy=sysinit.target

EOF

 # systemctl enable lvm2.service
```